# Entity Framework 5: Get List of Foreign Keys on an Entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework

Just a quick question on EF 5 code-first. How do I, at run-time, access the list of foreign keys that exists for a particular entity please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd think it would involve somehow looking at the mapping configurations loaded into the model, but no clue besides that. Just out of curiosity, why would you want to do that?

Comment: Actually entity can have no foreign keys, but there could be foreign keys in database. Consider parent entity with collection of child entities, mapped with `WithMany()`. In that case junction table will be generated and child entity will not have any foreign keys or navigation properties

Comment: I am trying to test my model, and would like to auto delete the created foreignkeys after each test. I am working with an existing database and wanted to make sure that I add make sense to the tests I create.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate through the child collection on the parent entity and save the id from each of the child entities.

Comment: Could you please explain further what you have posted above?

Answer (score 0):

I think the proper way to go around this without hacks is to use the [Metadata Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387116.aspx).

A few quick pointers:

- Use the [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696590.aspx) property of an instance of your derived [`DbContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.aspx) to retrieve its wrapped [`ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx) instance.  From there you can use the [`MetadataWorkspace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.metadataworkspace.aspx) property to retrieve the [`MetadataWorkSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace.aspx) instance.
- I would then look at one of the overloads of the [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataworkspace.gettype.aspx) method (for example) to retrieve the [`EdmType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmtype.aspx) for your entity.
- Once you have the EdmType, it's just a matter of looking up the properties of the entity it represents using its own [`MetadataProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataitem.metadataproperties.aspx) property.  You may filter each [`MetadataProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataproperty.aspx) object in the [`ReadOnlyMetadataCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339437.aspx) by looking at their [`BuiltInTypeKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.metadataproperty.builtintypekind.aspx), which value should be [`BuiltInTypeKind.NavigationProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb343228.aspx).

There may be other ways to do it, for example by somehow retrieving a collection of [`EdmMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.edmmember.aspx) objects for your entity, and then looking at their CLR [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx) by using [`GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gettype.aspx).  One of the possible types is [`NavigationProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.metadata.edm.navigationproperty.aspx).

**Disclaimer:**  Didn't test this.